# What drops to keep - endgame

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I'm playing Level 50 (CP300) Magicka Templar Healer, wearing mostly Light armor.

I am struggling with figuring out what to do with all the drops I have each day from running through daily dungeons or getting from chests. The inventory and bank space is limited and I don't know the worth of each item so most of Epic armor set pieces, weapons, or runes, I simply sell to vendors as these are bound on collect or equip anyway.

Is there any schema that could help me to understand which items I should keep or sell? Any hints or links to articles are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "schema" for that. Just think through it a bit. Personally I suggest this (there are other combinations except those I write here but... it falls mostly to this):

1. Bound on collect items:

   - Useful for you character -> obviously keep
   - Not useful for your character -> useful trait (this I will describe a bit below) -> keep
   - Not useful for your character -> lame trait -> sell at shop / deconstruct
2. Bound on equip:

   - Useful trait -> useful set (check mm or read a bit about the meta for this one - usually useful sets have really good prices on mm, especially jewls and weapons) -> sell on guild store
   - Sad trait -> useful set (check mm) -> sell on guild store
   - Sad trait -> lame set -> sell at shop / deconstruct

Now... everything falls into identifying good traits / sets. For sets:

- Useful -> monster sets and focused sets (there are a few exceptions but... mostly those)
- Sad sets -> rest

For traits (this list is HUGE so I'll just add the most common, if an item is not in this list think "how useful this can be"):

- Useful: Infused (on chest and helm), Divines (on any - especially gloves and waist), Reinforced (on hvy chest/helm), Nirn (any because of deconstruct), Precise, Sharp
- Sad: Prosperous and Training (on any), Sturdy (on light), Infused (on not chest/helm), Reinforced (on light), Powered (except on heal staff), Charged
- Situational: Impen (for pvp), Well fitted (for pvp), Infused on weapon (this can be really good or really bad)

A full list with explaning why would be huge (a few hundred combinations at least without even considering set stats) and would depend on so many factors (interaction between class, item, enchant, skill sets). When in doubt, check mm. If you don't have mm ask in guild :).